# How to force php curl to use 1.2 instead of tls 1.3?

Tags: php, libcurl, tls1.2, php-curl, tls1.3

I can't force curl to use tls 1.2. Whatever i tried its only uses tls 1.3.

There is my source code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
//also tried *6* => same response.
//also tried *5* => same response.
//also tried *4* => same response.
//also tried *3* => same response.
//also tried *2* => same response.
//also tried *1* => same response.
//also tried *0* => same response.

//also tried *CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2* => Undefined constant "CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2" error.


$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$tlsVer = json_decode($response, true);
echo "<h1>Your TSL version is: <u>" . ($tlsVer['tls_version'] ?: 'no TLS support') . "</u></h1>";
```

Response is always:

```
<h1>Your TSL version is: <u>TLS 1.3</u></h1>
```

Versions from **phpinfo()** is below:

- Curl version: 7.87.0
- Open ssl version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips 26 Jan 2017
- php version: 8.2.2

Edit: My server previously had curl 7.29.0, I updated to 7.87.0.

Edit2: More details from phpinfo();

**openssl**

- OpenSSL support: enabled
- OpenSSL Library Version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips 26 Jan 2017
- OpenSSL Header Version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k 26 Jan 2017
- Openssl default config: /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf

**curl**

- cURL support enabled
- cURL Information 7.87.0
- Age  10
- Features
- AsynchDNS: Yes
- CharConv: No
- Debug: No
- GSS-Negotiate: No
- IDN: No
- IPv6: Yes
- krb4: No
- Largefile: Yes
- libz: Yes
- NTLM: Yes
- NTLMWB: Yes
- SPNEGO: Yes
- SSL: Yes
- SSPI:No
- TLS-SRP: No
- Protocols: dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, gophers, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, mqtt, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
- Host: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
- SSL Version: NSS/3.79
- ZLib Version 1.2.7
- libSSH Version: libssh2/1.10.0

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2k is pretty old - did you try to use a more current version?

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce this on PHP 7.4.33 using cURL 7.74.0 - that constant `CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2`  exists, and the returned version is 1.2

Comment: The server may only support TLS 1.3?

Comment: "The server may only support TLS 1.3" - no, that's not the case for the given server

Comment: @HonkderHase My server previously had curl 7.29.0, I updated to 7.87.0. So i assumed server is not supporting only tls 1.3.

Comment: If you updated from 7.29.0, it's obvious that `CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2` didn't exist, because that was first added in 7.54.0. Make sure that PHP really uses any more current version of cURL

Comment: @NicoHaase my curl info from phpinfo(); https://prnt.sc/txCk1un-bqOx

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use screenshots for text content

Comment: An extract from the response - default options in curl ( & also manually asking for v1.2 ) yields - `"tls_version":"TLS 1.2","rating":"Probably Okay"}`  but then explicitly asking for v1.1 as a test yields `"tls_version":"TLS 1.1","rating":"Improvable"}`

Comment: @AtakanAkbulut with the new version use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2);` (notice `_MAX_`) and it'll work.

Comment: @SalmanA it returns Undefined constant "CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2" exception.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you probably using PHP on the shell to run the given snippet, which might use another PHP configuration than in the browser?

Comment: I am using Plek's built-in php version 8.2, I did not install any special php myself. 

I used as @SalmanA mentioned curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 393216) and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation on the CURL website](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html) is somewhat clear:

> CURLOPT_SSLVERSION - preferred TLS/SSL version
>
> [...]
>
> CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
> TLS v1.2 or later (Added in 7.34.0)

Note that it says *or later* but you want to enforce a *maximum*:

> The maximum TLS version can be set by using one of the
> CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_ macros below.
>
> CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2
> The flag defines maximum supported TLS version as TLS v1.2. (Added in
> 7.54.0)

The constants should be available in your combination of PHP + curl. If not, you can look them up [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h). `CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2` would be `0b110_00000000_00000000`.

Comment: it returns Undefined constant "CURL_SSLVERSION_MAX_TLSv1_2" exception.

Comment: Can you share more details? PHP 8.2.2 and cURL 7.87.0 sounds pretty recent

Comment: PHP gives me `393216` as the value for the constant. See if hard coding it works.

Comment: I used "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 393216)" and its worked! Thank you!